# Upgrading to Node 10 causing error in webpack build

Tags: node.js, webpack

I recently upgraded from Node 8 to Node 10, due to Node 8 being EOL this December, on my React frontend which I build with Webpack. I am getting an error when running webpack that looks like this:

```
/Users/ryandrew/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node[99538]: ../src/node_file.cc:943:void node::fs::Stat(const FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &): Assertion `(argc) == (4)' failed.
 1: 0x10003c597 node::Abort() [/Users/ryandrew/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node]
 2: 0x10003b5b9 node::AddEnvironmentCleanupHook(v8::Isolate*, void (*)(void*), void*) [/Users/ryandrew/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node]
 3: 0x100071e70 node::fs::Stat(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [/Users/ryandrew/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node]
 4: 0x10023663f v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(v8::internal::CallHandlerInfo*) [/Users/ryandrew/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node]
 5: 0x100235b81 v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::Object> v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::HandleApiCallHelper<false>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FunctionTemplateInfo>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::BuiltinArguments) [/Users/ryandrew/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node]
 6: 0x100235220 v8::internal::Builtin_Impl_HandleApiCall(v8::internal::BuiltinArguments, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/Users/ryandrew/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node]
 7: 0x608f2a5be3d
```

I've tried upgrading package versions, including webpack (which I migrated to v4 with WDS v3). I've found [this issue](https://github.com/dojo/cli-build-app/issues/93) which seems to have the same problem but I can't make sense of how to fix it.

Here's the full stack trace:

```
/Users/ryandrew/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node[99538]: ../src/node_file.cc:943:void node::fs::Stat(const FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &): Assertion `(argc) == (4)' failed.
 1: 0x10003c597 node::Abort() [/Users/ryandrew/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node]
 2: 0x10003b5b9 node::AddEnvironmentCleanupHook(v8::Isolate*, void (*)(void*), void*) [/Users/ryandrew/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node]
 3: 0x100071e70 node::fs::Stat(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [/Users/ryandrew/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node]
 4: 0x10023663f v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(v8::internal::CallHandlerInfo*) [/Users/ryandrew/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node]
 5: 0x100235b81 v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::Object> v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::HandleApiCallHelper<false>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FunctionTemplateInfo>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::BuiltinArguments) [/Users/ryandrew/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node]
 6: 0x100235220 v8::internal::Builtin_Impl_HandleApiCall(v8::internal::BuiltinArguments, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/Users/ryandrew/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node]
 7: 0x608f2a5be3d
```

Let me know what I can provide here to help out.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was to upgrade the version of my `node-sass` dependency. If you're facing this issue, I recommend you check all your packages to ensure they're compatible with the new Node version you're using.

Answer (score 1):

I got same error. And spent a lot of time locating the issue.

In my case, once upgrading `webpack-dev-middleware` from 2.x.x to 3.x.x, the issue is gone.